# What is wrong with this Answer?

Tags: discussion

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27989039/752842).
I am unsure of how to deal with it. I don't think it is a good answer.

It only provide links, although not duplicate because the links are more a guide than a solution to the problem.

Is it a link-only answer? Should be considered a comment?

Also has the "link-only" for flagging been removed? I can not see that option.

Finally it is ok to ask this here? I am asking because I want to understand better SO policies for flagging answers, but it may not be the appropriate place.

Comment: That's a link only answer, but can be easily fixed by editing in the linked questions's answers (with proper attribution).

Comment: @AndréDaniel I wanted to validate my interpretation before asking him to add data

Comment: It's fine to ask if you're not sure. I would have preferred actual code for an answer like this.

Comment: It is an answer.  It is not one that he worked on for an hour.  Well, that's okay, it's not like everybody has an hour of his time to spare.  Why don't you post a better answer?

Comment: @HansPassant I am asking for reference, not everyone has an hour but just linking stuff is not right either, because later on links get lost and the answer is useless. And for as long as I remember I thought links only answers were not considered good, has that changed?

Comment: @HansPassant also if you check he has answered me saying he didn't mean that to be a answer.

Comment: @HansPassant I never considered the answer useless, if so I would have down-voted it. I wanted to understand if it was considered  a good answer.  And I am not harassing him, I posted politely to him and advised to post as comment, because I have seen in the past people getting lots of down-votes for posting comments in the answers.

Comment: Worth mentioning: _"Also has the "link-only" for flagging been removed?"_ There hasn't been a dedicated "link-only" reason (as far as I can tell). People have been using "Not an Answer". For some guidance on how to handle these answers, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) and [most importantly, this faq post.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-it-is-not-an-answer)

Comment: @Kendra thanks, maybe i got confused with another site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, readers should be able to make use of an answer even if they don't follow the links, and that answer doesn't meet that requirement.

Even though I think that the answer can be improved otherwise, I don't see anything else that I would consider unsatisfactory in, so I think that the fact that you need to follow the links for it to be useful is the main problem.